# How to I get the outputlist in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to merge two ordered lists and I think I'm doing the right thing but how do I output the List L?

```
?merge([1,3,4],[2,5,6],L).

merge([],[],_):-!.
merge([X|SX],[],L):- merge(SX,[],[X|L]).
merge([],[Y|YS],L):- merge([],YS,[Y|L]).
merge([X|SX],[Y|YS],L):- X<Y, merge(SX,[Y|YS],[X|L]).
merge([X|SX],[Y|YS],L):- X>=Y, merge([X|SX],YS,[Y|L]).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting a binding for `L` because in fact your procedure does not instantiate it further.

You seem to be using an accumulator, but forgot to use an auxiliary parameter for it.
Also, using an accumulator you build the list in reverse so you would need reverse it in the base case:

```
merge(X, Y, L):-
  merge(X, Y, [], L).

merge([],[],L, L1):- reverse(L, L1).
merge([X|SX],[],L, L1):- merge(SX,[],[X|L], L1).
merge([],[Y|YS],L, L1):- merge([],YS,[Y|L], L1).
merge([X|SX],[Y|YS],L, L1):- X<Y, merge(SX,[Y|YS],[X|L], L1).
merge([X|SX],[Y|YS],L, L1):- X>=Y, merge([X|SX],YS,[Y|L], L1).
```

Sample run:

```
?- merge([1,3,4],[2,5,6],L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ;
false.
```

You may also rewrite your procedure so as to directly "add" the item in the head of each clause:

```
merge([],[],[]).
merge([X|SX],[],[X|L]):- merge(SX,[],L).
merge([],[Y|YS],[Y|L]):- merge([],YS,L).
merge([X|SX],[Y|YS],[X|L]):- X<Y, merge(SX,[Y|YS],L).
merge([X|SX],[Y|YS],[Y|L]):- X>=Y, merge([X|SX],YS,L).
```

Comment: Clause ```merge([X|SX],[],[X|L]) :- merge(SX,[],L).```can be replaced by ```merge(Xs,[],Xs).``` and clause ```merge([],[Y|YS],[Y|L]) :- merge([],YS,L).```can be replaced by ```merge([],Ys,Ys).```.

Comment: @slago: I just "tweaked" OPs code. The code, as is, will fail if fed with a non list, whereas with your suggestions it would succeed for example with  `merge([this|is_not_a_list],[],L).`